# синхронный callback

Tags: javascript

В некой сторонней библиотеке JavaScript есть объект, в котором одно из свойств - это callback функция (метод), которая вызывается где-то в недрах кода библиотеки. Эта функция должна возвращать строку. Например:

```
var obj = {
  formatter: function(){ 
    var str = "12345";
    return str;
  }
}
```

В этой функции нужно выполнить запрос на удаленный сервер, чтобы сформировать возвращаемую строку, т.е.

```
var obj = {
  formatter: function(){ 
    var str = "12345";
    var addStr = getDataFromServer();
    return str+addStr;
  }
}
```

Вопрос - как нужно написать функцию getDataFromServer(), чтобы она была синхронной?
Я уже пробовал через промисы, но не могу вернуть значение из их callback функции -

```
var obj = {
    formatter: function() {
        var str = "12345";
        var addStr; //undefined
        funcpromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function() { //аналог запроса на сервер
                var val = "12345";
                resolve(val)
            }, 5000);
        });
        funcpromise.then(function(val) {
                addStr = val; // здесь addStr == "12345"  
            })
            // здесь addStr undefined и это понятно, т.к. запрос к серверу асинхронный
        return str + addStr;
    }
}
```

Как дождаться того, чтобы addStr все-таки получила значение и основная функция вернула его через return?
Проблема в том, что return из метода formatter будет раньше, чем then. Метод уже будет вызван библиотекой и уже отработает и его уже не будут вызывать второй раз, когда придет then. Т.о. нужно ждать результата от сервера и потом делать return.

Comment: Никак, придумывай другой вариант или меняй библиотеку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам пример [отсюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await)

```
async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("готово!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // будет ждать, пока промис не выполнится (*)

  alert(result); // "готово!"
}

f();
```

При асинхронных вызовах это не возможно, поскольку JS однопоточный - это значит ваш асинхронный вызов не будет работать пока не получит управление. Но вы можете отправить запрос на сервер синхронно и ожидать ответа, но в таком варианте у вас приложение подвиснет в ожидании ответа. пример с [XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest#sinhronnye-zaprosy)

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('GET', '/article/xmlhttprequest/hello.txt', false);

try {
  xhr.send();
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    alert(`Ошибка ${xhr.status}: ${xhr.statusText}`);
  } else {
    alert(xhr.response);
  }
} catch(err) { // для отлова ошибок используем конструкцию try...catch вместо onerror
  alert("Запрос не удался");
}
```

Comment: 1. Этот код даже не скомпилирутся. 2. Так работать не будет.

Comment: @Qwertiy этот хоть компилируется?

Comment: Этот - да, но в этом вопросе он бесполезен.

Comment: @Qwertiy добавил ему пример чтоб не питал илюзий

Comment: Синхронные запросы не только не рекомендуются из-за того, что вешают страницу, но и вообще под жирным вопросом - стандарт уже разрешает браузеру не выполнять их, а сразу кидать исключение, и в момент, когда гугл решит, что пора от них избавляться, всё развалится. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Difuf.png - из https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-open()-method

Comment: @Qwertiy По хорошему конечно это все делается асинхронно и обрабатывается соответственно когда будет что